azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_categories leads to an error
Terraform Diagnostic Categories called an error on subscription level diagnostic.
azurerm provider version: 3.105.0
Implementation:
data "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_categories" "all" {   
  resource_id = "/subscriptions/dxxbxfxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" 
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "all" {  

  name = "forward_data_to-${value.eventhub_name}"

  target_resource_id             = value.target_resource_id
  eventhub_name                  = value.eventhub_name
  eventhub_authorization_rule_id = azurerm_eventhub_namespace_authorization_rule.all.id

  dynamic "enabled_log" {
    for_each = toset([
      for log_category in data.azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_categories.all.log_category_types : log_category
      if length(value.log_categories) == 0 || contains(value.log_categories, log_category)
    ])

    content {
      category = enabled_log.value
    }
  }

  dynamic "metric" {
    for_each = toset([
      for metrics in data.azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_categories.all.metrics : metrics
      if value.metrics_enabled == true && (length(value.metrics) == 0 || contains(value.metrics, metrics))
    ])

    content {
      category = metric.value
    }
  }
}



Error: retrieving Diagnostics Categories for Resource "Scope (Scope: "/subscriptions/dxxbxfxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")": unexpected status 400 (400 Bad Request) with response: {"code":"ResourceTypeNotSupported","message":"The resource type '/' does not support diagnostic settings."}

The module works perfectly on the contayner level.
A solution could be to change the logic and provide a log categories list manually instead of using the data block.
Maybe someone knows how to use this data module with the subscription level resources?
